# Is field.setAccessible(true) bad practice?

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, private, getter

In Java I am trying to use reflection to iterate over the declared fields so I can get at the annotations, as well as the underlying value of the field itself:

```
   for(Field field : CustomObject.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
       field.setAccessible(true);
       Object value = field.get(CustomObject);
       CustomAnnotation annotation = field.getAnnotation(CustomAnnotation.class);
       if (annotation != null) {
           //do stuff with annotation and object's value for this field
       }
    }
```

In this case the field may be private, which means I cannot access it directly with `field.get()` unless I set it as accessible first.

1. Is this bad practice? Even though it seems to work I cannot help but feel like this violates some crucial OOP principle.
2. Do I have to turn `setAccessible` to `false` once I am done?
3. Is there a better way to access the object's underlying value by somehow invoking its getter?

Comment: *For #2:* No. `setAccessible()` changes the particular `Field` instance you have (assuming you're allowed). If you call `getDeclaredFields()` again, you'll get different `Field` instances (still representing the same fields, though), and those `Field` instances won't have access to private field values unless you also call `setAccessible()` on those.

Comment: @Andreas Is this considered an appropriate way to get the value?

Comment: Answer: it depends on how you're going to use the field/the annotations on it. There are certain types of libraries like ORM mapping libraries and injection frameworks where it could be appropriate because there is a good reason the let the framework do something with the private variable. But for most purposes, especially purposes that are not some framework or library implementing some general functionality, it's a bad idea.