# How to re move "This accessibility bypass should be removed." by using Reflect

Tags: java, spring-boot, reflection, sonarlint

I have done the below code

```
public static <T> T mergeObjects(T draft, T existing)
      throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, NoSuchMethodException,
          InvocationTargetException {
    Class<?> clazz = draft.getClass();
    Field[] fields = clazz.getDeclaredFields();
    Object returnValue = clazz.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance();
    for (Field field : fields) {
      field.setAccessible(true);
      Object draftValue = field.get(draft);
      Object existingValue = field.get(existing);
      if (Objects.equals(existingValue, draftValue)) field.set(returnValue, existingValue);
      else field.set(returnValue, draftValue);
    }
    return (T) returnValue;
  }
```

but it's giving the sonar lint issue for setter at

1. field.setAccessible(true);
2. if (Objects.equals(existingValue, draftValue)) field.set(returnValue, existingValue);
3. else field.set(returnValue, draftValue);

I have tried many things but not working.
Can anyone know hoe to resolve it, please tell me.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to remove those lint warnings.  You are basically breaking type abstraction in that method, and Sonar is never going to be happy with you doing that.

Comment: so is there any other way of doing it, can you please tell me

Comment: Well one way would be to implement the merge functionality on a per-class basis, without using reflection.  Alternatively ignore or suppress the warnings.  It is up to you (as the developer) to decide which of the warnings are important.  And how much time it is worth spending on recoding to fix warnings.

Comment: No, actually the requirement is like that only, otherwise, I have to do so much of unnecessary code and I think that's not right.

Comment: So ... suppress the warnings then!  Basically >you< need to decide which of the alternatives is best for you.   You don't need my permission to decide :-)

Answer (score 0):

- If you **just** want to remove the lint issue, you can use `org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(field);` and `ReflectionUtils.setField(field,target,value)`
- example code:

```
ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible(field);//no sonar lint issue
```

- Warning:this solution didn't solve any potential issue, because the code in `makeAccessible` also use the `field.setAccessible(true);` with some check if statement, just use a static util method to get around the sonar check. If you care about the potential issue, pls check the "useful link" in below.
- ReflectionUtils.makeAccessible code:

```
    public static void makeAccessible(Field field) {
        if ((!Modifier.isPublic(field.getModifiers()) || !Modifier.isPublic(field.getDeclaringClass().getModifiers()) || Modifier.isFinal(field.getModifiers())) && !field.isAccessible()) {
            field.setAccessible(true);
        }
    }
```

- useful link:

1. [is-field-setaccessibletrue-bad-practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38948383/is-field-setaccessibletrue-bad-practice)
2. [java-reflection-impact-of-setaccessibletrue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10638826/java-reflection-impact-of-setaccessibletrue)
3. [SEC05 wiki](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/java/SEC05-J.+Do+not+use+reflection+to+increase+accessibility+of+classes%2C+methods%2C+or+fields)